# Stop Re-Rendering of Parent Components. Only Re-Render Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-select, formik

I have a React-Select Field, inside a Formik Field, that when you select an item from the dropdown options, all the Parent Components are rerendered. This is the deepest child component available in the Container.

And it re-renders 4 Parents. Which is kind of Problematic. I want to limit the rerender of the Component to only itself.

```
The above happens because each Child Process passes
props to the Container, which is the master form.
And onSubmit it takes all the info(props) and makes the API Call.
```

I tried doing it with `shouldComponentUpdate` but no luck. I tried to do it with `SetState`, but that though fell in the water, as I couldn't make it work(Got a ton of errors).

**--TLDR--**
THE PROBLEM:
Make a Component retain the rendering to only itself. External Components used in it `Formik` and `React-Select`.

Here is the code for that:

```
            <div className="w-50">
              <Field
                name={`${keyField}.${index}.permissions`}
                render={({ field: { value, name }, form: { setFieldValue, setFieldTouched } }) => (
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="namespace-permissions" className="font-weight-medium">
                      Permissions in Namespace <Asterisk />
                    </label>
                    <Select
                      isMulti
                      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                      id="namespace-permissions"
                      defaultValue={convertNamespaceToDefaultValue(
                        dependencies.namespacePermissions,
                        value
                      )}
                      options={convertNamespaceToSelect(dependencies.namespacePermissions)}
                      onChangeCallback={values => {
                        setFieldValue(name, convertSelectToNamespacesData(values));
                        setFieldTouched(name, true);
                      }}
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage name={name} component={FormErrorMessage} />
                  </div>
                )}
              />
            </div>
```

The `dependacies` prop is what makes the trip up the tree, to the master form Props, and rerenders the entire Component Tree. This also, ties with another question I had yesterday, about react-select's `closeMenuOnSelect={false}` not working correctly.

^This is the reason why that happens. Thank you..

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide all 4 parent Components code, as it would take an enormous amount of time, finding relevant parts to paste. The same goes for a CodeSandbox example. Sorry if I am not helping, but I just asked because I thought there might be a quick solution.

Comment: It's hard to give you a specific answer here, but the only way I know how to achieve this is using shouldComponentUpdate. That's what handles the rendering of components in React.

Comment: Tried it, but it seems it doesn't seem to encapsulate it in the component itself, which from my understanding it shouldn't. Anyway, thank you for your time..

Comment: Formik updates form model everytime there's a change in your form which apprently may be every keystroke. You are passed a new object which forces component to re-render. You can consider wrapping your field in something called `FastField` available from formik but you have to be careful on what you are using htere as it will only update if the fieldName value changes. Value being actual value including entire object. If it keeps pointing to the same object  and you rely on the value within it, then it wont update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would be able to do this with the libraries that you're using. But when I don't want my components rendering unnecessarily I use `React.memo` it will shallow compare the `props` object and decide if needs to update.

[**From React DOCS**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate)

**WITHOUT REACT MEMO**

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <Parent1/>
  );
}

function Parent1(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Parent1...');

  const [parentState,setParentState] = React.useState(true);

  return(
    <Parent2
      setParentState={setParentState}
    />
  );
}

function Parent2(props) {

  console.log('Rendering Parent2...');

  return(
    <Child
      setParentState={props.setParentState}
    />
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  
  console.log('Rendering Child...');
  
  return(
    <button onClick={()=>props.setParentState((prevState)=>!prevState)}>Update ParentState</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**WITH REACT.MEMO**

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <Parent1/>
  );
}

function Parent1(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Parent1...');

  const [parentState,setParentState] = React.useState(true);

  return(
    <Parent2
      setParentState={setParentState}
    />
  );
}


const Parent2 = React.memo(function Parent2(props) {

  console.log('Rendering Parent2...');

  return(
    <Child
      setParentState={props.setParentState}
    />
  );
}
);

const Child = React.memo(function Child(props) {
  
  console.log('Rendering Child...');
  
  return(
    <button onClick={()=>props.setParentState((prevState)=>!prevState)}>Update ParentState</button>
  );
}
);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will look into the `React.memo`. But I think the problem lies with formik, cause even while `shouldComponentUpdate` was implemented correctly. Formik's fields still re-renders the entire form. Which in my case there are 5 (3 siblings of my components - 1 Parent). I might be wrong, but since everything is wrapped in a Formik `Form` it re-renders everything every time something changes. Anyways thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

I would check if Formik's onSubmit is being called and if that's triggering the tree to re-render. If you have a button with `type=button` that could be triggering a form submit.

There is also a bug with Formik before v2 where Field will mount and unmount all of it's children on every update if given the render function through `render` or `component` prop. Instead just pass the render function as the Fields child.